# Android HttpURLConnection, POST: Error message, Node type is required

Tags: android, rest, post, drupal

I have problem posting content to my Drupal site from Android.
I get the error message:

> Node type is required

.

I have tested the url in Postman. And it works. I am able to add new articles. Its just on Android that i have this error.

I have a question. Do I need to add the session id and session name, to make a post? If so, can you please give an example of how this is achieved.
This is my first time making a post request. Not sure how much of the code is correct. I had trouble finding a good tutorial for beginners.

In Manifest I have

```
android.permission.INTERNET<br>
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

I have saved my token, session id and session name.

```
public String session_name;
public String session_id;
public String token;
```

Posting of values

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String address = "http://app.flickgo.com/apistuff/node.json";
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(address);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            String userCredentials = "My_Username:My_Password";
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-CSRF-Token", token);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "utf-8"));

            //i want to save the title of an article
            String title = "Mobile";
            String input = ("{\"title\":\""+title+"\",\"type\":\"article\"}");

            writer.write(input);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            InputStream inputStream;
            // get stream
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            } else {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
            }
            // parse stream
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String temp, response = "";
            while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response += temp;
            }
            // put into JSONObject
            jsonObject.put("Content", response);
            jsonObject.put("Message", urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
            jsonObject.put("Length", urlConnection.getContentLength());
            jsonObject.put("Type", urlConnection.getContentType());

            return jsonObject.toString();
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            return e.toString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the issue by using this code.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://yoursite/endpoint/node");  
try {
            //get title and body UI elements
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
            TextView txtBody = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editBody);

            //extract text from UI elements and remove extra spaces
            title= txtTitle.getText().toString().trim();
            body=txtBody.getText().toString().trim();

            // set json to StringEntity

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity( " { \"title\":\""+title+"\",\"type\":\"article\",\"body\":{\"und\":[{ \"value\":\""+body+"\"}]}}");
            //  set httpPost Entity
            httppost.setEntity(se);

            // Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httppost.setHeader("Cookie",session_name+"="+session_id);
            httppost.setHeader("X-CSRF-Token", session_token);

            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.v("Response from Drupal: ", EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

            return 0;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("Error adding article",e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have struggled with this problem for so long.